# Trading bitcoin with paypal?

Tags: exchanges, paypal

Is it possible to trade bitcoin with paypal and stay anonymous?

How the big trading sites are trading bitcoins and recieve payments with paypal and keep the users anonymous (because there isn't an option of anonymous payment in paypal).

Comment: Do trading sites really use PayPal at all?  There are a lot of problems with that, because PayPal payments can be reversed while Bitcoin cannot.  See the [tag:paypal] tag for lots more details.

Comment: your best bet is to find a bitcoin ATM or meet someone in person

Comment: You can always just buy your bitcoin non-anonymously and then use a [mixing service.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mixing_service)

Answer (score 1):

Try LocalBitcoins:

https://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/paypal/

https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/paypal/

If you are selling Bitcoins make sure the buyer is reputable - pick a Sell Bitcoins online advertisement with green thumb.

Please note that the buy price is higher with PayPal, because the sellers price in the risk of doing business on PayPal.

If you trading with unknown party make sure you [follow the risk mitigation procedures](https://localbitcoins.com/guides/how-to-sell-bitcoins-online#toc5). PayPal, by the reports, is very common method for doing fraudulent purchases.

Usually exchanges expose no user information about the trades, so they are very hard to trace. But if you wish to add an extra layer to hide the origin of Bitcoins you can use [mixer](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mixing_service), which itself might not be a safe procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this method works:

- Buy an Amazon Gift card from [Gyft](http://www.gyft.com) using PayPal to pay
- Use that Amazon credit to buy Wishlists from [amz2bitcoin](https://www.amz2btc.com)
- Bitcoins for the purchase deposited directly into your wallet address

It's anonymous, relatively fast, and a good alternative to localbitcoins.  It's also a helluva lot cheaper than going through Virwox.